# Why the system cannot find the specified path?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, terraform

I have an issue where I am trying to run: terraform init in module folder of my project and I am receiving an error below. When I am running terraform init not in module but in the main folder everything is right I am getting: Terraform has been successfully initialized!
I am working on Windows 10 with Terraform version 0.14.6

I have a file in specific directory. Why am I receiving this error?

```
Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "~> 3.24.1"...
- Installing hashicorp/aws v3.24.1...

Error: Failed to install provider

Error while installing hashicorp/aws v3.24.1: open
.terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\aws\3.24.1\windows_amd64\terraform-provider-aws_v3.24.1_x5.exe:
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Answer (score 3):

I moved all files to c:\terraform folder and it works fine. I don't why because I have turned on long path in windows and the whole path is 116 signs not over 255.