# Error while installing hashicorp/azurerm v2.73.0: open

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

A `terraform init` command using terraform v1.0.5 is failing with the following error:

```
- Installing hashicorp/azurerm v2.73.0...
2021-09-02T17:53:54.661-0700 [TRACE] providercache.Dir.InstallPackage: installing registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.73.0 from https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-azurerm/2.73.0/terraform-provider-azurerm_2.73.0_windows_amd64.zip
2021-09-02T17:53:54.661-0700 [TRACE] HTTP client GET request to https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-azurerm/2.73.0/terraform-provider-azurerm_2.73.0_windows_amd64.zip
2021-09-02T17:54:24.762-0700 [DEBUG] Provider signed by 34365D9472D7468F HashiCorp Security (hashicorp.com/security) <security@hashicorp.com>
╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│
│ Error while installing hashicorp/azurerm v2.73.0: open
│ .terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\azurerm\2.73.0\windows_amd64\terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.73.0_x5.exe: The system cannot find the path
│ specified.
╵
```

We removed all extraneous terraform code to isolate the problem to simply the provider configuration.

The complete code for the bare-minimum example that triggers this error includes both a module definition and a call to that module definition.

The complete code for the bare minimum call to the module definition is:

```
module "name-of-module" {
  source = "..\\..\\..\\..\\modules\\name-of-module"

  subscriptionId     = var.subscriptionId
  tenantId           = var.tenantId
  clientId           = var.clientId
  clientSecret       = var.clientSecret
  resourceGroupName  = var.resourceGroupName
  pipeAzureRegion    = var.resourceGroupRegion

}

##Input variables.  The client referred to is an App Registration.
variable "subscriptionId" { }
variable "tenantId" { }
variable "clientId" { }
variable "clientSecret" { }
variable "resourceGroupName" { }
variable "resourceGroupRegion" { }
```

The complete code for the bare minimum module definition is:

```
variable "subscriptionId" { }
variable "tenantId" { }
#The client referred to is an App Registration.
variable "clientId" { }
variable "clientSecret" { }
variable "resourceGroupName" { }
variable "pipeAzureRegion" { }

terraform {

  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.73.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
    subscription_id = var.subscriptionId
    client_id       = var.clientId
    client_secret   = var.clientSecret
    tenant_id       = var.tenantId

    features { }

}
```

That is 100% of the code.  We removed everything else to isolate the possible cause of the problem.

> **What is causing the error message that we posted above?**

Comment: here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66098947/why-the-system-cannot-find-the-specified-path) to the answer

Comment: @RaviKumarCH Two questions not addressed in the link you posted: 1. What is the max number of characters allowed?  2. Is there a setting we can adjust to increase the number of allowed characters?   ....  We ask these two questions because this is done through automation and we would have to set controls on how paths are constructed, etc if we are not able to configure terraform to accept longer paths.

Comment: Terraform's error messages are sometimes not self-explanatory. To be able to find the cause of the error, please enable debug by setting the environment variables as below.  


**PowerShell**
`> $env:TF_LOG="TRACE"
> $env:TF_LOG_PATH="terraform.txt"`  

**Bash**
`$ export TF_LOG="TRACE"
$ export TF_LOG_PATH="terraform.txt"`  


Once set, please provide the log output to determine the cause of the issue.